# Python SQLalchemy 1.4 ORM: What do I need to import in order to use in_()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been stuck with trying to use in_().
I just can't seem to figure out what to import in order to use it.

I'm using:

1. python 3.9.4
2. SQLalchemy 1.4.11

preferrably ORM, but CORE advice is still fine if the distinction is relevant for this question at all.

According to SQLalchemy 1.4 docs, it saysin_() method is at `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.in_`
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.in_

However, I just can't figure out what to import in order to use it. I've tried the follwings but to no avail:

```
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import ColumnOperators      # Trial 1
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators             # Trial 2
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.in_         # Trial 3
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, and_, in_    # Trial 4, and_ or_ are here, but not in_
```

I've tried searching, but what I've found was how to use the method, and their code blocks didn't reveal the import lines.

By the way, I'm trying to make the following statement work when I pass it to `session.excute()`

```
    stmt = (select(User)
                .where(id.in_(user_ids)))
```

Comment: What happens when you try to use it after using those imports?

Comment: @mkrieger1 hi, #1 succeeds to load the file, but throws exception when start using the SQL with in_().  #2~#4 all give invalid syntax.

Comment: Then you have apparently solved the import problem and now have other problems.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I thought I have too, but it doesn't seem to fit into ordinary ORM statements like and_, or_ because I have to instantiate the class object.

Comment: Instead of `.filter_by()` try using `.where(User.id.in_(user_ids))`

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you for your correction. I will make a change. However, it did not make in_ to work. Thanks though.

Comment: FWIW, [this code](https://pastebin.com/0Zh2iQCx) works for me.

Comment: @GordThompson Hmm... I'm sorry, but could you give me a hint about your import lines...? I couldn't get it to work even though I tried it after making the change.

Comment: The code including the imports is [here](https://pastebin.com/hbnCe28w).

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you so much. I don't know what I did right after checking out your codes, but after importing Column, everything started to work... However, I'm confused b/c it still works even when I don't import Column now.... I'll do more testings with my codes using your imports. Thank you!!